# Retry mechanism for Scheduler in Python

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have been working on scheduling tasks in python. There are two scenarios

1. Scheduler needs to hit the server for every hour to fetch the data of that hour (200 ok)
2. Retry mechanism: In case of any failure from server side (i.e. response ), it has to hit for every 30 seconds until the response from server is 200 ok.
   The following code has been tried.

**Ex: Success---1hr---Success---1hr---Fail--30sec--Fail--30sec--Success---1hr---Fail--30sec**

```
class sched:
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(timezone=utc)
    startTime = datetime.now
    
    def __init__(self,tm:TM,scheduler):
        self.tm = tm
        self.code = tm.fun1()
        self.job = scheduler.add_job(self.tm.fun1, 
        trigger='interval', hour = '1',timezone='UTC')

    def start_sched(self,scheduler):
        if (scheduler.state != STATE_STOPPED) is False: #Scheduler is not running
            scheduler.start()
            
    def retry_sched(self,scheduler,code):
        if (scheduler.state != STATE_STOPPED) is True: #Scheduler is running 
            if self.code is False: #But some failure happens
                time.sleep(30) #For Every 30 secs it has to hit back
                scheduler.start()
```

I am able to run the scheduler and it is hitting for every hour successfully. But when the response from server is not successful, even then also it takes 1hr to hit again.

Do I need to create a new job in case of failure? Isn't it double work?
Is there a way to run the same job for both success and failure cases.
Please help me out I am really struck.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably keep the retry loop in the current thread, like this:

```
def retry_sched(self, scheduler, code):
    if (scheduler.state != STATE_STOPPED):  # Scheduler is running
        while not self.code:  # But some failure happens
            time.sleep(30)  # For Every 30 secs it has to hit back
```

You might want to consider some retry count to exit the loop after too many failures.